# python http requests; browser not detected

Tags: python, session, browser, http-post, python-requests

I want to login to my account with the following structure:

```
import requests
session=requests.Session()
resp=session.get('https://mywebsite.com/login')
cont=resp.content
post_data={'user':'username', 'pass':'password'}
post_response=session.post(url='https://mywebsite.com/login', data=post_data}
print cont
```

The following error occurs:

**Browser Error: Your browser version looks incompatible**

Comment: [Follow up question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010820/enabling-javascript-and-cookies-in-python-requests)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `User-Agent` to something that the website thinks is compatible. You can do it like this,

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'
}
r = session.post('https://mywebsite.com/login', data=post_data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to send a correct User-Agent, for example:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0',
}

post_response=session.post(url='https://mywebsite.com/login', data=post_data, headers=headers)
```